# DBFirst, EF, MVC - inserting spaces in fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My dbfirst EF with MVC project is inserting values into the SQl database with spaces at the end of the value. In addition to trimming the spaces in my sql queries, is there anything I can do right in the code itself to insert values without spaces into the SQL table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could just be that you have a char column instead of a varchar.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258242(v=sql.80).aspx

[n]Char columns are fixed length, so even if you only have a 3 char string, it will add spaces to fill up the whole column.  You'll want [n]VarChar if you want a variable length string.

Answer (score 0):

Trim the spaces before you insert.

You can use `string.Trim()`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx

Comment: Since most of the code is auto generated with dbfirst, EF, using dbcontext (code generation template) I am not able to look for code where it inserts the records.. any idea where to change this trim setting?

Comment: It's not inside EF code - it's when YOU set the values on entity properties.